# read xls file and re-export without lose initial data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spreadsheet, export-to-excel

I m using “spreadsheet”ruby gem to generate xls files.

I have already an xls file “MyFile.xls”  which contains many sheets: sh_01, sh_02, sh_03 …
I want to read the name of the last sheet (sh_last_number) and add a new sheet called “sh_last_number+1” to this file (MyFile.xls) and write some data on it.
In other words, I have to open it (read data) and write on it at the same time.
If this idea can’t be realized with Spreadsheet, is their another gem more efficient?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with the spreadsheet gem. Since you are working with excel files, you may need to require the excel component of the gem if you are using an older version:

```
require 'spreadsheet' # You may need to require 'spreadsheet/excel'
```

Then working with and writing pages is simple. To open the workbook (xls file with multiple pages) you do something like:

```
@workbook = Spreadsheet.open("MyFile.xls")
```

And then to add a sheet to the workbook you've opened, you simply:

```
new_sheet = "sh_#{@workbook.worksheets.size + 1}"
@worksheet = @workbook.create_worksheet(:name => new_sheet)
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Thanks Sean, error was occurred => undefined_method create_worksheet. I strayed an other example and I was able to read data only and not writing or adding an other sheet

Comment: Strange... I tested it in irb and it worked for me. Are you using an older version of the gem? Maybe try: @worksheet = @workbook.add_worksheet("test")

Comment: If you are using an older version of the gem, do require 'spreadsheet/excel' and then @worksheet = @workbook.add_worksheet("test")

Comment: hello, it works, but when I re-open MyFile.xls, there is no sheet added.